# Clear text field after keypress enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, textfield

I'm using a simple chat script and need a way to clear the text field after pressing enter.

I got it to clear text field on mouse click with `onfocus` but keypress eludes me. Also is there a way to do both with one command to make the code cleaner?

```
<form onsubmit="chat.sendMsg(); return false;">
    <input onfocus="if(this.value !== '') {this.value=''}" onblur="if(this.value == '')" type="text" id="msg" name="msg" autofocus="true" placeholder="Type Your Meassage Here" />
    <input type="submit" value="Enter" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<form onsubmit="chat.sendMsg(); this.msg.value = ''; return false;">
    <input onfocus="if(this.value !== '') {this.value=''}" onblur="if(this.value == '')" type="text" id="msg" name="msg" autofocus="true" placeholder="Type Your Meassage Here" />
    <input type="submit" value="Enter" />
</form>
```

or

```
<form onsubmit="chat.sendMsg(); this[0].value = ''; return false;">
        <input onfocus="if(this.value !== '') {this.value=''}" onblur="if(this.value == '')" type="text" id="msg" name="msg" autofocus="true" placeholder="Type Your Meassage Here" />
        <input type="submit" value="Enter" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, using the event attributes is, these days, outdated to the point of bad practice. Instead, hook up your events using JS. As you've tagged the question with jQuery, try this:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="msg" name="msg" autofocus="true" placeholder="Type Your Meassage Here" />
    <input type="submit" value="Enter" />
</form>
```

```js
$(function() {
    $('form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        chat.sendMsg();
        $('#msg').val(''); // clear the message box
    });

    $('#msg').on('focus', function() {
        this.value = '';
    });
});
```

Note that I removed the `blur` handler as it didn't actually do anything.

Comment: ...but I wouldn't even bother testing `if (this.value !== '')` -- if you're going to clear it, just blindly clear it.