# Selenium with Python - send_keys entering text but then immediately clearing the text.....no idea why

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I hope someone can help.  I've tried everything.  First I couldnt enter the text at all and realised I had to first switch to the frame (no id or name so I had to use an index of 4).

Then I can see the text being entered into all of my fields and then quickly being cleared out.  I've nothing in my code that does that.

Anybody know how to resolve this behaviour?

```
driver.switch_to.frame(4)
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.find_element_by_name("ctl00$Content$ucxList$txtSearchByTextSearchByEventExRef").send_keys("bump this up!");
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.find_element_by_name("ctl00$Content$ucxList$txtSearchByTextSearchByEventName").send_keys("bump this up!");
```

`

Comment: This may be a wild guess that's off the mark, and it only came to mind because I recently had to implement some jQuery that would remove entered text. I presume the website you're accessing could have code that's meant to protect against automated manipulation based on the time it is taking to fill in fields, and removing the text if filled before a certain time threshold. The code might look something like what's in this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31504884/42346

Comment: Can try a '.clear()' after the FindElementBy and before the sendkeys so see if it makes a difference

Comment: Hi Nazard - it didnt make a difference.  I had already tried it before I just took it out to keep my code clean as the fields are already empty.

Comment: Anyone any other thoughts on a resolution?  @mechanical_meat - Is that implicity wait not waiting 5 seconds?

Comment: @showmeyourskills: great question. You could try switching to `time.sleep(5)`. If the DOM is ready, `.implicitly_wait(5)` will proceed when its ready, not necessarily waiting those 5 seconds.